# C# - Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

I'm creating a system in C# and MySQL, but I keep getting this frustrating error, "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts". I've tried many different things but nothing has worked, could someone PLEASE try to help me?

```
public bool tryLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=hostremoved;user=user_removed;password=passwordremoved;database=databaseremoved;");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_name = '" + username + "' AND user_pass = '" + password + "';");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read() != false)
        {

            if (reader.IsDBNull(0) == true)
            {
                cmd.Connection.Close();
                reader.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Connection.Close();
                reader.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tryLogin(txtuser.Text, txtpass.Text) == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login worked!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login failed!");
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Okay, I will fix those 2 things,but do you know how to help with the actual problem I need help with?

Answer (score 1):

If it is not the firewall, and the database is setup to listen for remote connections, then you should check that your user credentials are configured so that the specified database will accept a connection from the given IP. If the user can only connect from localhost, then you'll need to login as root and issue a GRANT statement, like:

```
GRANT ALL ON yourDbName.* TO 'yourUser'@'yourIP' IDENTIFIED BY "yourPassword";
```

For more on using GRANT, see:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it a firewall issue? Check that the machine the MySql instance is running on is able to accept connection through the firewall.

Comment: It could be, but I'm not exactly sure how to access the firewall settings as the server isn't hosted off my own machine. Is there a way to do it through PhpMyAdmin or something?

Comment: Okay nevermind, I've whitelisted my IP but it still isn't working, got any suggestions?

Comment: Is this database hosted by a 3rd party company or is it one you control? Is your database configured to only listen on local ports possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone! I had to whitelist my IP on my firewall and it worked!